# Update table with rolling average from itself

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to update a temp table with a rolling average calculation (MS Access 2010.)

As a select query, this works to calculate a 3 month rolling average but is slow so I'd rather have the values stored and updated only when necessary:

```
SELECT tempQORDistGrouped.Type, tempQORDistGrouped.Supplier, tempQORDistGrouped.DepBkMo, tempQORDistGrouped.Amt, tempQORDistGrouped.Brands, tempQORDistGrouped.T2, tempQORDistGrouped.Brand, (select avg(rolavg.Amt) from tempQORDistGrouped as rolavg 
  where rolavg.Type = tempQORDistGrouped.Type
  and rolavg.Supplier = tempQORDistGrouped.Supplier
  and rolavg.Brands = tempQORDistGrouped.Brands
  and rolavg.Brand = tempQORDistGrouped.Brand
  and rolavg.DepBkMo between dateadd("m",-2,tempQORDistGrouped.DepBkMo) and tempQORDistGrouped.depbkmo) AS AvgAmt
FROM tempQORDistGrouped;
```

I've tried the update query below but I think my inner join syntax is bad as it won't recognize x1.Type as a valid field (do I need to include these as part of the inner join fields rather than in the where clause??):

```
UPDATE tempQORDistGrouped AS x1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT itmID,  avg(Amt) AS RolAvg
  FROM tempQORDistGrouped 
  WHERE tempQORDistGrouped.Type = x1.Type
  AND tempQORDistGrouped.Brand = x1.Brand
  AND tempQORDistGrouped.Brands = x1.Brands
  AND tempQORDistGrouped.T2 = x1.T2
  AND tempQORDistGrouped.DepBkMo between dateadd("m",-2,x1.DepBkMo) and x1.DepBkMo 
  GROUP BY itmID
  ) AS x2
ON x1.itmID = x2.itmID
SET x1.3MonthRollingAmt = x2.RolAvg;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work. 
I am doing a column level query to calculated the `AVG` and then mapping it back to the rest of the columns

Try this:

```
UPDATE tempQORDistGrouped AS x1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT itmID
        , (
            SELECT avg(Amt) amt
            FROM tempQORDistGrouped x4
            WHERE x4.Type = x3.Type
                AND x4.Brand = x3.Brand
                AND x4.Brands = x3.Brands
                AND x4.T2 = x3.T2
                AND x4.DepBkMo BETWEEN dateadd("m", - 2, x3.DepBkMo) AND x3.DepBkMo
            ) AS RolAvg
        , x3.Brand
        , x3.Brands
        , x3.DepBkMo
        , x3.T2
    FROM tempQORDistGrouped x3
    ) AS x2
    ON x1.itmID = x2.itmID
        AND x1.Brand = x2.Brand
        AND x1.Brands = x2.Brands
        AND x1.T2 = x2.T2
        AND x1.DepBkMo BETWEEN dateadd("m", - 2, x2.DepBkMo) AND x2.DepBkMo    
SET x1.3MonthRollingAmt = x2.RolAvg;
```

Comment: Thanks SoulTrain, gave this a go and had to fix it up for a minor syntax error but now I'm getting the error "Operation must use an updateable query" from Access when I try to execute.  Doesn't really make sense because I'm updating a table.  Googled around and can't find anything that works to fix it so if anyone has an idea on this it would be great!

Comment: I tried this in a sql server env and it works, I dont have a MS access setup to check against. Could you change the query to a Select and see if its returning the correct result in Access.